# Spring Data jpa (hibernate) nullpointer Exception when adding List of Entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

first my Code.

**Specialization**

```
@Entity
public class Specialization {

    @Id
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="att_id", referencedColumnName="ID")
    private List<Attribute> attributes;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

**Attribute**

```
@Entity
public class Attribute {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private double scaling;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

My Problem is that i get a following Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindOneToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:864)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:779)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:728)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 98 more
```

This Exception only Occurs after adding the attribute `attributes` to the Class `Specialization`.  So without this attribute everything works fine, but if I add this attribute, the exception comes up. I don't get what I'm doing wrong.
Maybe somebody could find my mistake?

**Additional information:**

Hibernate Core Version: 4.3.7. Final.

There is another Entity `GameClass` with a oneToMany relationship to Specialization => Every `GameClass` has multiple `Specialization`s and every `Specialization` has multiple `Attribute`s.

Don't know if this matters but this is a Spring-Boot application

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: you should post the relevant code where you're adding the list

Comment: Sorry i think i did not make myself clear. With adding the list i mean i add the List as an Attribute to the Class `Specialization`. So without this attribute everything works fine, but if I add this attribute, the exception comes up. The Version of Hibernate Core is 4.3.7. Final

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got my mistake. Sleeping a bit helped.
I've mixed up the relations.

If one `Specialization` has many `Attribute`s, the annotations should look like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="specc_id", referencedColumnName = "name")
private List<Attribute> attributes;
```

and **NOT** like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="att_id", referencedColumnName="ID")
private List<Attribute> attributes;
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be silver bullet, but For me it went away when I removed `referencedColumnName` from below:

```
@JoinColumn(name="att_id")
```